# Projective Texture / Shadow Mapping -- Why is the perspective division performed in the fragment shader?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shadow-mapping

I've just worked my way through [this OpenGL shadow mapping tutorial](https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-Lighting/Shadows/Shadow-Mapping).
While I understand the basic algorithm, one thing puzzles me:
During the 2nd render pass all vertices are transformed into the clip space of the light source. This is done by multiplying them with the light's view-projection matrix in the vertex shader:

```
vs_out.FragPosLightSpace = lightSpaceMatrix * vec4(vs_out.FragPos, 1.0);
```

However, for texture lookup into the shadow map a perspective division is needed. This is done in the fragment shader:

```
float ShadowCalculation(vec4 fragPosLightSpace)
{
    // perform perspective divide
    vec3 projCoords = fragPosLightSpace.xyz / fragPosLightSpace.w;
    //continue w. texture lookup
    [...]
}
```

So my question is - why can't I perform the perspective division in the vertex shader? I did try moving the division from fragment to vertex shader in my otherwise finished shadow mapping code, and ended up with some really weird artifacts. So I guess it has something to do with the interpolation performed by the rasterizer, but I would like a more detailed explanation if possible.

Comment: "*This is done in the fragment shader*" That's silly. OpenGL has [dedicated `Proj` texture accessing functions that do the divide for you](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Sampler_(GLSL)#Projective_texture_access). I'm surprised that the tutorial doesn't bother to use them, since letting you know they exist is half the point of such a tutorial in the first place.